# What experiment would disprove string theory?

Tags: string-theory, experimental-physics

I know that there's big controversy between two groups of physicists:

1. those who support string theory (most of them, I think)
2. and those who oppose it.

One of the arguments of the second group is that there's no way to disprove the correctness of the string theory.

So my question is if there's any defined experiment that would disprove string theory?

Comment: It's not as big a controversy as you might think.  The vast majority of physicists don't work on anything close to string theory at all.

Comment: I saw a comment (seems to have vanished) to one of the answers that the view, heavily thrashed out in Smolin's book, that ST assumes a flat background whereas GR clearly accounts for dynamically bending spacetime is a bit moot insofar that GR could be construed of as being in a flat background with some fancy additions. Did this comment have any merit - could Lee Smolin truly have been unaware of such an interpretation? Or could it be something kind of trivial like the curved manifold of a GR solution can be embedded in a higher dimensional flat space (Whitney embedding). Comments anyone?

Comment: @SeleneRoutley The question is not if the theory can be written as if there is a flat background, but rather if the flat background has physical consequences. Deser showed in the 70s that if you assume flat background and adding a spin 2 field, then require that the interacting theory is consistent, you get GR. But once you get GR, the flat background becomes undetectable. In fact Deser showed that whatever background you start with, it becomes unobservable. It’s like doing Newtonian physics in one specific frame: you can do it but it does not mean imply that there is a notion of absolute rest

Comment: @Andrea Thanks for such an interesting comment. i'm a quantum optics and strictly classical GTR kind of girl, so string theory is a bit beyond me, But i am acutely aware that the kind of things you mentioned are possible, and it is lovely to have it confirmed by someone in the know. Actually, i agree the important thing is if the resulting flat background to the modified interpretation has physical consequences, but i am still perplexed that Lee Smolin SEEMED not to be aware of e.g. Deser's work. I guess the translation into a book for a lay audience might have lost something in translation.

Answer (score 357, accepted):

One can disprove string theory by many observations that will almost certainly not occur, for example:

1. By detecting **Lorentz violation** at high energies: string theory predicts that the Lorentz symmetry is exact at any energy scale; recent experiments by the Fermi satellite and others have shown that the Lorentz symmetry works even at the Planck scale with a precision much better than 100% and the accuracy may improve in the near future; for example, if an experiment ever claimed that a particle is moving faster than light, string theory predicts that an error will be found in that experiment
2. By detecting a **violation of the equivalence principle**; it's been tested with the relative accuracy of $10^{-16}$ and it's unlikely that a violation will occur; string theory predicts that the law is exact
3. By detecting a **mathematical inconsistency** in our world, for example that $2+2$ can be equal both to $4$ as well as $5$; such an observation would make the existing alternatives of string theory conceivable alternatives because all of them are mathematically inconsistent as theories of gravity; clearly, nothing of the sort will occur; also, one could find out a previously unknown mathematical inconsistency of string theory - even this seems extremely unlikely after the neverending successful tests
4. By experimentally proving that the **information is lost** in the black holes, or anything else that contradicts general properties of quantum gravity as predicted by string theory, e.g. that the high center-of-mass-energy regime is dominated by black hole production and/or that the black holes have the **right entropy**; string theory implies that the information is preserved in any processes in the asymptotical Minkowski space, including the Hawking radiation, and confirms the Hawking-Bekenstein claims as the right semiclassical approximation; obviously, you also disprove string theory by proving that **gravitons don't exist**; if you could prove that gravity is an entropic force, it would therefore rule out string theory as well
5. By experimentally proving that the world doesn't contain gravity, fermions, or isn't described by quantum field theories at low energies; or that the general **postulates of quantum mechanics don't work**; string theory predicts that these approximations work and the postulates of quantum mechanics are exactly valid while the alternatives of string theory predict that nothing like the Standard Model etc. is possible
6. By experimentally showing that the real world contradicts some of the general features predicted by all string vacua which are not satisfied by the **"Swampland"** QFTs as explained by Cumrun Vafa; if we lived in the swampland, our world couldn't be described by anything inside the landscape of string theory; the generic predictions of string theory probably include the fact that gravity is the weakest force, moduli spaces have a finite volume and similar predictions that seem to be satisfied so far
7. **By mapping the whole landscape**, calculating the accurate predictions of each vacuum for the particle physics (masses, couplings, mixings), and showing that none of them is compatible with the experimentally measured parameters of particle physics within the known error margins; this route to disprove string theory is hard but possible in principle, too (although the full mathematical machinery to calculate the properties of any vacuum at any accuracy isn't quite available today, even in principle)
8. **By analyzing physics experimentally up to the Planck scale** and showing that our world contains neither **supersymmetry** nor **extra dimensions** at any scale. If you check that there is no SUSY up to a certain higher scale, you will increase the probability that string theory is not relevant for our Universe but it won't be a full proof
9. A convincing observation of **varying fundamental constants** such as the fine-structure constant would disprove string theory unless some other unlikely predictions of some string models that allow such variability would be observed at the same time

The reason why it's hard if not impossible to disprove string theory in practice is that string theory - as a qualitative framework that must replace quantum field theory if one wants to include both successes of QFT as well as GR - has already been established. There's nothing wrong with it; the fact that a theory is hard to exclude in practice is just another way of saying that it is already shown to be "probably true" according to the observations that have shaped our expectations of future observations. Science requires that hypotheses have to be disprovable in principle, and the list above surely shows that string theory is. The "criticism" is usually directed against string theory but not quantum field theory; but this is a reflection of a deep misunderstanding of what string theory predicts; or a deep misunderstanding of the processes of the scientific method; or both.

In science, one can only exclude a theory that contradicts the observations. However, the landscape of string theory predicts the same set of possible observations at low energies as quantum field theories. At long distances, string theory and QFT as the frameworks are indistinguishable; they just have different methods to parameterize the detailed possibilities. In QFT, one chooses the particle content and determines the continuous values of the couplings and masses; in string theory, one only chooses some discrete information about the topology of the compact manifold and the discrete fluxes and branes. Although the number of discrete possibilities is large, all the continuous numbers follow from these discrete choices, at any accuracy.

So the validity of QFT and string theory is equivalent from the viewpoint of doable experiments at low energies. The difference is that QFT can't include consistent gravity, in a quantum framework, while string theory also automatically predicts a consistent quantum gravity. That's an advantage of string theory, not a disadvantage. There is no known disadvantage of string theory relative to QFT. For this reason, it is *at least* as established as QFT. It can't realistically go away.

In particular, it's been shown in the AdS/CFT correspondence that string theory is automatically the full framework describing the dynamics of theories such as gauge theories; it's equivalent to their behavior in the limit when the number of colors is large and in related limits. This proof can't be "unproved" again: string theory has attached itself to the gauge theories as the more complete description. The latter, older theory - gauge theory - has been experimentally established, so string theory can never be removed from physics anymore. It's a part of physics to stay with us much like QCD or anything else in physics. The question is only what is the right vacuum or background to describe the world around us. Of course, this remains a question with a lot of unknowns. But that doesn't mean that everything, including the need for string theory, remains unknown.

What could happen - although it is extremely, extremely unlikely - is that a consistent, non-stringy competitor to string theory is also able to predict the same features of the Universe as string theory can emerge in the future. (I am carefully watching all new ideas.) If this competitor began to look even more consistent with the observed details of the Universe, it could supersede or even replace string theory. It seems almost obvious that there exists no "competing" theory because the landscape of possible unifying theories has been pretty much mapped, it is very diverse, and whenever all consistency conditions are carefully imposed, one finds out that he returns to the full-fledged string/M-theory in one of its diverse descriptions.

Even in the absence of string theory, it could hypothetically happen that new experiments will discover new phenomena that are impossible - at least unnatural - according to string theory. Obviously, people would have to find a proper description of these phenomena. For example, if there were preons inside electrons, they would need some explanation. They seem incompatible with the string model building as we know it today.

But even if such a new surprising observation were made, a significant fraction of the theorists would obviously try to find an explanation within the framework of string theory, and that's obviously the right strategy. Others could try to find an explanation elsewhere. But neverending attempts to "get rid of string theory" are almost as unreasonable as attempts to "get rid of relativity" or "get rid of quantum mechanics" or "get rid of mathematics" within physics. You simply can't do it because those things have already been showed to work at some level. Physics hasn't yet reached the very final endpoint - the complete understanding of everything - but that doesn't mean that it's plausible that physics may easily return to the pre-string, pre-quantum, pre-relativistic, or pre-mathematical era again. It almost certainly won't.

Comment: By saying this: "By mapping the whole landscape, calculating the predictions of each vacuum for the particle physics, and by showing that none of them is compatible with the experimentally measured parameters of particle physics; this route to disprove string theory is hard but possible in principle, too".  You're basically saying, "we've created a model with a huge number of parameters, and we've found a great fit!".  And string theory is qualitatively different from Relativity and QM, as the latter two theories have made predictions that were tested, not just satisfied consistency tests.

Comment: If I had an accelerator that could access energies equal to ten planck energies, or something absurd like that, so that the string vacuum would be irrelevant, would it then be possible to calculate a cross-section that would then be testable by this accelerator?

Comment: Dear Jerry, first of all, "we" haven't created string theory. String theory is of a purely natural origin. It is as exceptional a mathematical structure as $E_8$ Lie group or any other unique object in mathematics. People can only discover it, not invent it. Second, string theory has no adjustable continuous parameters whatsoever - it's one of its advantages over quantum field theories. So you have all these considerations upside down. Finally, the number of solutions to some equations is whatever it is. You may disagree with this fact but that's the last thing you can do against maths.

Comment: Dear Jerry, all the detailed phenomena at the intermediate scales depend on the choice of the vacuum, and all the trans-Planckian phenomena - with center-of-mass energy above the Planck energy - are dominated by black hole physics which is qualitatively described by low-curvature general relativity again and is totally universal across all stringy vacua - or any hypothetical consistent theories of quantum gravity, for that matter. If these general wisdoms about the black hole dominance were disproved experimentally, string theory would have to go, too.

Comment: So basically, if the universe behaves in a way that contradicts the predictions of QFT with weak gravity (extremely unlikely), or if information is destroyed by black holes (almost inconceivably difficult to test, even with Planck energy accelerators) or by mapping the landscape, and showing it doesn't match our universe (incredibly computationally infeasible).

Comment: Dear Peter, you have just apparently omitted 90% of the methods, not sure why, but OK. At any rate, the falsification is hard but this is true, almost by definition, for any conceivable mathematically consistent hypothesis that addresses the Planck scale - or any other very high-energy - physics. This difficulty is here because of the very problems we're trying to answer - and it has no impact on the validity of string theory whatsoever.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94521/discussion-on-answer-by-lubos-motl-what-experiment-would-disprove-string-theory).

Comment: You've got to clarify the "By detecting a mathematical inconsistency in our world, for example that 2+2 can be equal both to 4 as well as 5" part, for it's nothing less than cringe-worthy for a neo-platonian mathematician. An inconsistency detected in experiments can only show that the theory (a mathematical model) is inapplicable; it doesn't translate into inconsistency of mathematics itself.

Comment: Right. That is exactly my point. There cannot be an inconsistency in mathematics. And because much of the knowledge about string theory is composed of mathematical proofs, this knowledge can never go away. Your misrepresentation of a theory as a "mathematical model" is mostly a way for you to deceive yourself. String theory isn't just a "model". There are important subtle differences between the words and string theory is much grander and more applicable than anything that can be called a model. Many of the derivations directly apply to observations.

Comment: *"There cannot be an inconsistency in mathematics"* expresses a faith that [mathematicians themselves are unwilling to express](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40920/what-if-current-foundations-of-mathematics-are-inconsistent).

Answer (score 115):

Since many people seem to have very odd ideas about this, let's address this from a much simpler point of view.

Let's suppose you have a friend who only knows math at the level of arithmetic of positive integers.  You try to tell him about the existence of negative numbers, and he tells you,

> That's stupid, there's obviously no such thing as "negative" numbers, how can I possibly measure something so stupid?  Can you have negative one apple?  No, you can't.  I can owe you a positive one apple, but there's clearly no such thing as negative apples.

How can you start to argue that there is such a thing as negative numbers?

A very powerful first step is mathematical consistency.  You can list all of the abstract properties you believe to characterize everything about positive integer arithmetic:

- For all $a,b,c$, $a(b+c) = ab+ac$
- For all $a,b$, $a+b=b+a$, $ab=ba$
- There exists a number, called $0$, such that, for all $a$, $a+0=0+a=a$, $a0=0a=0$
- There exists a number, called $1$, such that, for all $a$, $1a=a1=a$

(note that, in sharp contrast to the case of real numbers, the first property can be proved with induction, and need not be an axiom.  Similarly, other listed properties can be proved from other ones designated to be more basic if one wishes, which can not be done in the case of the reals.)

So, once you both agree that these axioms characterize the positive integers completely, you can show that these hypothetical negative numbers, based on their formal properties, are consistent with the above axioms.  What does this show?

*The positive integers, with the addition of the negative integers, can do at least as much as the positive integers by themselves.*

(**STOP**  At this point, pause to realize how *powerful* this constraint is!!  How many other ways could one generalize arithmetic, *at this level*, to something else that is consistent with the properties you want?  Zero.  There is absolutely no other way to do it.  This is incredibly suggestive, and you should keep this in mind for the rest of the cartoon argument, and see how every argument that follows is secretly an aspect of this one!)

Your friend responds:

> Sure, you can write down toy models like that, and they may be consistent, but they don't correspond to reality.

Now, what else do you need to demonstrate to your friend to convince him of the validity of the negative numbers?

You find something else they can do that you can't do with the positive numbers alone.  Simply, you can state that every positive-integer-valued algebraic equation does not have a solution:

$$ x + 1 = 0 $$

does not have a solution.

But, it is a trivial fact that extending to the negative numbers allows you to solve such equations.  Then, all that's left to convince your friend of the validity of negative numbers is to show that this is equivalent to solving an ("a priori") *different* problem which only involves arithmetic of positive integers:

$$ x+1=0 \iff y + 1 = 1 $$

So, $y = 0$, and $y=x+1$ is equivalent to the other problem.

To be complete, we also have to consider problems that are "unique" to the negatives, such as $(-1)(-1) = 1$, but in the realm of integers, these are trivial matters that are reducible to the above.  Even in the case of reals, given the other things we've shown, these consequences are almost "guaranteed" to work out intuitively obviously.

Now, assuming your friend is a reasonable, logical, person, he must now believe in the validity of negative numbers.

What have we shown?

- Consistency, both with previous models and with itself
- The ability to solve new problems
- The reduction of *some* problems in the new language to problems in the old language

Now, to decide if this is a good model for a particular system, you must look at the subset of problems that did not have a solution before, and see if the new properties characterize that system.  In this case, that's trivial, because the properties of negative numbers are so obvious.  In the case of applying more complicated things to describe the details of physical situations, it's less obvious, because the structure of the theory, and the experiments, is not so simple.

How does this apply to string theory?  What must we show to convince a reasonable person of its validity?  Following the above argument, I claim:

- String theory reproduces (by construction) general relativity
- String theory reproduces (by construction) quantum mechanics (and by the above, quantum field theory)

So string theory is at least as good as the rest of the foundations of physics.  Stop again to marvel at how powerful this statement is!  Realistically, how many ways are there to consistently and non-trivially write a theory that reduces to GR and QFT?  Maybe more than one, but surely not many!

Now the question is--what new do we learn?  What additional constraints do we get out of string theory?  What problems in GR and QFT can be usefully written as *equivalent* problems in string theory?  What problems can string theory solve that are totally outside of the realm of GR and QFT?

Only the last of these is beyond the reach of current experiments.  The "natural" realm where string theory *dominates* the behavior of an experiment is at very high energies, or equivalently, very short distances.  Simple calculations show that these naive regions are well outside of direct detection by current experiments.  (Note that in the above example of negative numbers, the validity of the "theory" strictly in the corresponding realm didn't need to be directly addressed to make a very convincing argument; pause to reflect on why!)

However, theoretical "problems" with the previous theories, such as black hole information loss, can be solved with string theory.  Though these can't be experimentally verified, it's very suggestive that they admit the expected solution in addition to reproducing the right theories within the right limits.

There are two major successes of string theory that satisfy the other two requirements.

AdS/CFT allows us to solve *purely* field theory problems in terms of string theory.  In other words, we have solved a problem in the new language that we could already solve in the old language.  A bonus here is that it allows us to solve the problem precisely in a domain where the old language was difficult to deal with.

String theory also constrains, and specifies, the spectrum and properties of particles at low energies.  In principle (and in toy calculations), it tells us *all* of the couplings, generations of particles, species of particles, etc.  We don't yet know a description in string theory that gives us *exactly* the Standard Model, but the fact that it does constrain the low-energy phenomenology is a pretty powerful statement.

Really, all that's left to consider to convince a very skeptical reader is that one of the following things is true:

- It is **possible** for string theory to reproduce the Standard Model (e.g., it admits solutions with the correct gauge groups, chiral fermions, etc.)
- It is **not possible** for string theory to reproduce the Standard Model (e.g., there is no way to write down chiral theories, it does not admit the correct gauge groups, etc.   This is the case in, e.g., Kaluza-Klein models.)

I claim, and it is generally believed (for very good reasons), that the first of these is true.  There is no formal, complete, mathematical proof that this is the case, but there is absolutely no hint of anything going wrong, and we can get models very similar to the standard model.  Additionally, one can show that all of the basic features of the Standard Model, such as chiral fermions, the right number of generations, etc, are consistent with string theory.

We can also ask, what would it mean if string theory was wrong?  Really, this would signal that,

- The theory was mathematically inconsistent (there is no reason to believe this)
- At a fundamental level, either quantum mechanics or relativity failed in some fairly pathological way, such as a violation of Lorentz invariance, or unitarity.  This would indicate that a theory of everything would look radically different than anything written down so far; this is a very precarious claim--consider what would happen in the example of arithmetic in the above if there were something "wrong" with addition.
- The theory is consistent, and a generalization of GR and QFT, but is somehow not a generalization in the right "limit" in some sense.  This happens in, e.g., Kaluza-Klein theory, where chiral fermions can't be properly written down.  In that case, a solution is also suggested by a sufficiently careful analysis (and is one potential way to get to string theory).

Of these three possibilities, the first two are extremely unlikely.  The third is more likely, but given that it is known that all the basic features can show up, it would seem very strange if we could almost reproduce what we want, but not quite.  This would be like, in the arithmetic example, being able to reproduce all the properties we want, except for $1+ (-1) = 0$.

If you're careful, you can phrase my argument in a more formal way, in terms of what it precisely means to have a consistent generalization, in the sense of formal symbolic logic, if you like, and see what must "fail" in order for the contrapositive of the argument to be true.  (That is, (stuff) => strings are true, so ~strings => ~(stuff), and then unpack the possibilities for what ~(stuff) could mean in terms of its components!)

Comment: Your answer is a tour de force. I give it +1, with the caveat that I disagree with your statement that *"String theory reproduces (by construction) quantum mechanics"*. I do not know of any aspect of string theory or of any claims (speculative or otherwise) which could substantiate such a statement. We start of with the action (Nambu-Goto/Polykaov) for a string. This action describes a classical object. We go on to "quantize" this action following the standard prescriptions of quantum mechanics. In no way does QM *arise* from a stringy basis, IMHO. Please correct me if you think I'm mistaken.

Comment: Well it doesn't from an operator theory point of view, fix the quantization procedure or anything, so you can't really quite construct an "axiomatic qft" based off of it. But it is still *designed* to be appropriately quantum mechanical in the right limits.  But knowing, and using, quantum mechanics in advance is not an impediment to constructing it or to my statement ;).

Comment: I'm not accepting string theory as a consistent well-defined theory of physics until string theorists agree on the answer to the question: How does information escape from a black hole? Right now, I'm not even sure string theorists can correctly formulate the conditions that a string theory state is a black hole.

Comment: There are many papers addressing this. And there are interesting statements you can make in, e.g., AdS/CFT by thinking about how the field theory corresponds to black holes in the gravity dual. I believe Lubos's blog has a few discussions of this in fairly simple terms. Of course, many details are not yet understood, but the general idea certainly is.

Comment: I like the metaphor of the extension of the positive integers to the signed integers as a model for the extension of relativity+quantum theory to string theory. But I think a better metaphor is the extension of Euclid's axioms. It turned out there were multiple consistent (even "correct") extensions of the axioms. But of course, only one extension is "true" (or "real) for any given universe. This is rather the question being asked here: is there any experimental way to know which extension reflects reality?

Comment: To truly convince your friend that negative numbers are 'real,' I think you need to say everything you said plus one more thing: "So, given all of that, if you have an empty bank account and owe me ten dollars, how much money do you have?"  In other words, you have to link it back to physical reality.  I don't know much about string theory, but it seems that the gripes about it are more along the lines of how it treats (or doesn't treat) that last step.

Comment: This answer uses a lot of words to completely elide the difference between checking that a theory is mathematically self-consistent and checking that a theory is actually true. It's also mathematically self-consistent to say that gravity is an inverse cube force. That doesn't mean it's true -- you have to actually _check_ what it is.

Comment: @ClayWardell The answer to that question is that everyone has *infinite money*. At $ 0 bank account I can still spend money by borrowing over and over.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that physics is not mathematics

Answer (score 38):

The only way to 'test' string theory, is to actually figure out what it predicts first, which is ambiguous at the moment.

Contrary to most claims, String theory is actually a unique theory in that there are no adjustable free parameters.  However it has a large or possibly infinite amount of classical solutions or 'vacua'.  Most of these vacua look nothing like the real world, some (by some I mean it could be ~$10^{500}$) are very similar (in that they seem to correspond to low energy physics like the standard model), and at most one corresponds to the real world.

When you have specified a vacua, you then have fixed the predictions identically -- for everything (that's what it means to be a theory of everything).  So for instance, you could compute the mass of the electron to however many decimal places and then test it in the lab and also the vacua might make an unambiguous prediction for cosmological objects (e.g.: the existence of cosmic strings or domain walls).  We don't know exactly.

Of course absent a way to figure out which vacua corresponds to reality, we are left with the same problem that quantum field theory has.  Namely you actually have to go out and measure certain things first in order to make predictions (so for instance in the standard model we need to pin down the $26$ adjustable free parameters, like the Yukawa couplings, masses of elementary particles and so forth).. But once you have done that, you can then predict infinitely many other things, like scattering cross sections.

So in string theory, that would mean some way of whittling down $10^{500}$ vacua to a more human number, like $50$, $10$ or better $1$ or $0$ ($0$ means the theory is falsified).  Which requires doing scattering experiments at the Planck scale, which means a particle accelerator roughly on the scale of the Milky Way.

Of course, it may turn out that string theory makes unambiguous falsifiable predictions, but that really requires a great deal of theoretical work b/c it implies knowing something about not just the vacua that corresponds to the real world, but also the $10^{500}$ other ones if you get my meaning.  Still, we know that it does make some predictions.  For instance, the existence of the quanta of gravity is universal across all solutions.  Likewise, the fact that quantum mechanics and special relativity must hold is another robust prediction.

Comment: Nice answer @Columbia. My question is about your last sentence: *the fact that quantum mechanics and special relativity must hold [in string theory] is another robust prediction.* I've heard this said before and I don't see how these are "predictions" of string theory. The string action is covariant so relativity is obeyed. Quantization follows the rules of quantum mechanics. These ingredients are part of the setup from the get go. Perhaps I am misinterpreting the statement.

Comment: @SpaceCadet.  It is true that if you start learning st from GSW in the usual way that world sheet LI and Dirac QM are automatically there from the beginning.  So in a sense it is not surprising that they stay that way, although you could in principle imagine Lorentz breaking by anomalies.  However if you start from equally valid formulations of st where LI is not manifest ex: Light cone gauge, then it is always the case that it is recovered.  These are non trivial consistency checks.  Similarly with quantum mechanics, you often recover Dirac rules whenever you might have forgotten them

Comment: The point I think is that String theory is very tightly constrained, perhaps moreso than any other physical theory invented and its a bit of a culture shock to pause for a minute and appreciate just how much we took for granted in other theories.  There is no wiggle room really for theorists to come in and insert something by hand, b/c if one thing breaks then everything breaks and it usually happens in a very obvious and violent way.

Comment: From where this number of variants came from, 10^500? Why you do not know whether the number of possibilities finite or not?

Comment: @Annix the number of solutions to the dynamical equeations **IS** finite and well and well defined.

Comment: @Columbia Can we compute differential scattering cross section in string theory just like in QFT and get numbers as predictions? Could they have low energy implications? For example, if we compute the 4-point graviton amplitude in string theory and then compute scattering cross section and integrate over all possible angles, what is the relevance of that formula? One more question, what is the relation between 10d S-matrix and 4d S-matrix in string theory?

Answer (score 34):

String theory should come with a proposal for an experiment, and make some predictions about the results of the experiment; then we could check against the real results.

If a theory cannot come with any predictions, then it will disprove itself little by little ...

The problem is that, with string theory, this is extremely difficult to do, and string theorists have year in front of them to go in that direction; but if in 100 years we are still at the same status, then it would be a proof that string theory is unfruitful...

Comment: While a fair point, I don't think this really answers the question, as it will not be a disproof. :/

Comment: I agree, but my point is "there is no disproof experiments needed, just proof experiments": any experiment, one after the other, contribute to the "proof", but any single one of them can be a potential disproof.

Comment: Even if string theory is at the same level of development after 100 years, it won't be a proof of anything, certainly not that string theory is unfruitful. It'll just be very _likely_ that it's a useless theory, but we really won't know for sure without a specific prediction for some experimental result.

Comment: Certain ancient Greek philosophers theorized that matter came in chunks - the word 'atom' is Greek if I recall.  They were right though it wasn't until only 100 years ago anyone could be sure.  So a long time passing without verification should not discredit an idea.

Comment: It is very much the case that if a theory cannot make any verifiable predictions, it is a *useless* theory, whether it is correct or not, and should therefore not be pursued.

Comment: @Daren Demokritos of Abdera  s p e c u l a t e d  about atoms. ( plus a lot od rechurners) When atoms were introduced in science middle/end of 18th century it was based on chemical evidence (constant and multiple mass ratios) from the onset. Neither 2500 or 100 years of waiting for experimental results.

Comment: -1 There is no content in this answer.

Comment: @DarenW Ancient Greek philosophers did mention atoms, but their atoms have nothing to do with what we know as atoms today, because άτομο means something that cannot be divided in constituents and atoms certainly can. One could say that quarks are the atoms of the philosophers, but nobody is certain. Also, their theories were not just constrained by deficiencies in terms of experimental methods, but they mostly were too vague to be of any practical use for anything at all. Not to mention that no matter what one philosopher would say, another would claim the opposite. That said, I'm Greek!

Answer (score 22):

It is very hard to probe the scales of quantum gravity experimentally so there are very few possibilities for testing if string theory is incorrect as a unified theory encompassing quantum gravity. One of the few observations that has probed the Planck scale was the Fermi gamma ray telescope observation which showed that photons of different energy travel very close to the same speed over cosmic distances. If the result had shown a dispersion of speed it would have disproved string theory and encouraged physicist to look at other ideas.

Of course any observation that disproves quantum theory or general relativity will also disprove string theory, but the real interest is in observations that relate directly to quantum gravity because the separate theories are already well established in their own regimes.

Although it is hard to get direct experimental input for any theory of quantum gravity the constraints on any theory from the logical requirement to combine quantum theory and gravity into one consistent theory for physics are already tremendously strong. In particular there should be some perturbative low energy limit that describes gravity in terms of gravitons which interact with matter. Despite much effort string theory is the only approach that can accomplish this and it is very hard to conceive of a second way. In fact it is very surprising that there is this one way because it requires almost miraculous cancellations of anomalies to make it work. This gives many people the confidence that string theory is the correct path to follow.

Ultimately there needs to be some definitive observation of a quantum gravitational effect that supports string theory. As I said, there are not many possibilities for such observations at present, but this would be a problem for any alternative theory of quantum gravity too.

It is possible that we might get lucky and observe large extra dimensions at the LHC, but there is no reason to expect that. Another possibility that I think is a little more plausible is that supersymmetry would be observed and found to take a form that supports a supergravity origin. Still we have no moral right to expect the universe to hand us such an easy clue and string theory does not promise one.

Such difficulties do not mean that string theory is wrong as some opponents say. It just means that it is going to be difficult to explore quantum gravity empirically.

There has still been constant progress in understanding string theory from the theoretical side and that is continuing. More work needs to be done on the non-perturbative side of string theory so that we can better understand its implications for cosmology. There is some hope that an observation of relic gravitational waves or even low frequency radio waves left over from the big bang may have a characteristic signature dependent on quantum gravitational effects. Again we have no moral rights to demand that such an observation will be forthcoming but it might if we are lucky.

Comment: Your indication of the importance of quantum gravity to this question is a great point.

Answer (score 17):

If understood correctly (?) something Lubos once said, string theory requires torsion (in GR) to be zero.  There are experiments underway/planned right now to measure torsion.  Therefore not only is there an experimental disproof of string theory, but we should get the data soon.

Comment: @Lubos Motl Could you please confirm whether Michael understood you right. Nonzero torsion is something we nonstringtheoretical mere mortals can readily understand, and, if Michael's understanding is right, then this is an extremely important and concrete test for string theory.

Comment: could you please give a link or a summary of the experiments. Nonzero torsion would in one way be a strict telling against GR, but this is not "serious" in the sense that we would then have Einstein–Cartan theory: different in form but not really different in the grounding ideas of GR. Maybe the same could be said of string theory? Please, someone might like to comment, since I know a bit about GR, but nothing about ST - is there an ST that reduces to Einstein Cartan, rather than plain GR? Or is such a thing fundamentally different?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: , @ Michael C Price:   This must be true since String theory only provides little $\alpha'$ corrections to GR, and does not  affect it any such way such that there is any intention of torsion.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 16):

String theory, was constructed with the idea that at low energies it should reduce to the quantum mechanical and particle world that we see every day. This is analogous to the correspondence principle in quantum mechanics.

In some sense, any experiment that discredits quantum mechanics will cause a serious re-examination of string theory, however, as many experimentalists will joke, a theorist will always find a way to fix his theory to match the observations. In any case, quantum theory seems very well supported and is unlikely that it will be discredited any time soon

Direct tests of string theory, however,  will have to wait until we can probe much higher energies.

Comment: ...or someone finds a much more powerful and clever "magnifier" for string theoretical effects then is currently known.

Comment: And what are those effects? What string theory predicts for high energies that other theories do not?

Comment: What @Anixx says is right in this case. This does not provide an answer to the question.     The OP has clearly  heard this multiple times and wants a specificic answer.

Answer (score 8):

String excitations, rspt lack thereof. Problem is however that unless you believe in a theory with a lowered Planck scale, you'll have to go to energies we'll never be able to reach in the lab to test this regime. But at least in principle it's falsifiable.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by other posters, the key question is energy.

At very high energy levels, approaching some of the quantum gravity 'limits', the string-like  nature of fundamental particles would become increasingly apparent. (In terms of an experiment, at a high enough energy level, for instance, there would likely be new specific 'resonances' of the material that could be identified.)

You might also find [this article interesting](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2010/09/stringy-quantum/).

Answer (score 4):

To disprove the string theory I would say is not very likely; but there are two ways that would cause trouble in string theory: one theoretical and one by experiment. Both unlikely to happen soon, (an both unlikely to ever disprove it, because the string theory seems to be in the right way, at least until now by far.)
- If one would like to "dissprove it" at least in an initial approximation to cause some scepticism, should find a theory which solves at least as many problens as the string theory solves, and deals with at least some of the remaining problems of the string theory. (Even if this other theory exists, it will take several decades after its discovery to evolve anyway..)

-Experimentally as everyone else said we need to achieve higher energies on earth, or some better way to  locate and detect these higher energies in universe possibly. To achieve or locate somewhere, the energies where string theory effects are detectable will take many many years from now-at least that is the common belief.

-The "argument" that sometimes I listen the string theory is not a theory or is wrong because it can not be verified or disproved is competely wrong. Simply because this is not an argument. 
If we have to reach higher energies to see the string theory, then we just have to; is very possible that this is the physics. In any case even simpler physics stories like the one of neutrino which critised (with the critics of that time to be:'not even wrong' or the most optimistic "there is no practical way of observing the neutrino"); with Pauli and Fermi doing the theoretical prediction in ~1930 and the discovery of the Cowan and Reines in 1956 can teach us some things...

In one sentence the answer to your last line is:
Until now there is no experiment or detector that can verify the string theory. In the future it is a belief that this will happen when we will be able to achieve or locate somewhere these higher energies that the stringy effects become detectable.

Answer (score -4):

Disprove string theory by empirically falsifying a string theory postulate.  No postulate can be defended or it need not be postulated.  Falsify BRST invariance and string theories collapse.  Falsify the Equivalence Principle (EP) and the whole of physics needs a rewrite. No measurable observable violates the EP.  All continuous and most approximately continuous symmetries bow to Noether's theorems.

You need an observable (so you know it is there) that is calculable (so you know how much) but not measurable, that is an absolutely discontinuous symmetry - and a test for its divergent consequences.  Are shoes different from socks when given a left foot?  By how much, yours versus mine? Quantitative chirality is calculated in any number of dimensions, J. Math. Phys. 40, 4587 (1999) and

http://petitjeanmichel.free.fr/itoweb.petitjean.freeware.html#QCM 
(http://www.mazepath.com/uncleal/norbors.gif
Solution optical rotations ignore atomic mass distribution)

Chop a pair of shoes into $\mathrm{mm}^2$ pieces. Sort them left versus right.  Chirality is an emergent property.  It depends on scale.  To test the EP against a pair of shoes, one would need a shoe built on the smallest possible scale - a few atoms - and rather a lot of shoes to sum to a measurable divergence.  Physics cannot do that, but chemistry can.

If anything can break string theory (we cannot be smarter than Luboš, but we *can* be orthogonal) then

http://www.mazepath.com/uncleal/erotor1.jpg 
   Two geometric Eötvös experiments.  $0.113\, \mathrm{nm}^3$ volume/α-quartz unit cell.  $40\, \mathrm{grams}$ net as $8$ single crystal test masses compare $6.68×10^{22}$ pairs of opposite shoes (pairs of $9$-atom enantiomorphic unit cells, the test mass array cube's opposite vertical sides).

DO NOT bet your grade on that!  Betting a December Swedish dinner is acceptable, especially if its main course is surströmming,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgV2imaOCao

Comment: This is promoting non-mainstream physics, which is not the topic of this site

Comment: String theory is rigorously derived.  One CANNOT disprove it within physics.  That does not mean it is true.  It means an experiment outside Official Truth is required.  1) "Particle physics is not mirror symmetric - shouted down, PNAS 14(7) 544 (1928), http://www.pnas.org/content/14/7/544.full.pdf+htm  2) "Particle physics is not mirror symmetric - Nobel Prize - but not for the experimenter, Phys. Rev. 105(4) 1413 (1957), http://prola.aps.org/pdf/PR/v105/i4/p1413_1