# Has string theory predicted any experimently verified results?

Tags: string-theory, experimental-physics

I'm just getting into string theory and I'm wondering if it has made any unique predictions that have been verified by experiment?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5057/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi newguy. We encourage people asking a question to [do a quick search of the site first](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=string+theory+experiment) to see if their question (or a similar one) has already been asked.

Comment: You should see a "delete" option at the bottom-left of the post in a browser. That said, you are not expected to remove questions closed as duplicates. Your question can serve as a sign-post to the next person who forms the questions using this title rather than the title of the earlier version(s).