# Seeing the strings of the string theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, string-theory

Can we possibly create such a light wave which has a wavelength of Planck length so we can see the strings that the theory supposes there are?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5057/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This is similar to asking if we can create an elastic wave at the wavelength comparable to the size of atoms forming the solid where it spreads. No, because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photons don't exist at the string length scale, or perhaps it's better to say that the photon is a poor description of the behaviour at that scale.

The photon arises from quantum field theory when we quantise the electromagnetic four potential. But quantum field theory emerges as a low energy approximation to string theory. So at string energy scales we have no quantum field theory and therefore we have no photons. At those energies everything is described using interactions of strings.

So we would not ever be able to *see* a string simply because at the string scale that concept has no meaning.

Comment: The string theory does have the photon. One can either describe the photon as a massless state of an open string or as a linearized deformation of the background in which the string propagates (which will be a gauge field living in the D-brane where the ending points are attached). Both descriptions are equivalent due to the state-operator correspondence of CFTs in the worldsheet formulation, so one is allowed to push this view of "seeing" the string using photons, which can be *translated* to a stringy scattering amplitude but do not need to.