# Can one calculate scattering amplitudes and cross-sections in string theory?

Tags: experimental-physics, string-theory, renormalization

Can one calculate scattering amplitudes (even tree level) and find cross-sections? Shouldn't loop amplitudes be easier in string theory than QFT because the UV divergences in string theory should not be as bad (isn't that part of the reason string theory is supposed to be better than QFT)?

What is stopping one from calculating amplitudes and observable quantities(cross-sections and decay rates), and what makes that hard?

Comment: String theory makes a lot of predictions, including on the number of spacetime dimensions. There are statements, though, that string theory doesn't make any predictions that can currently be tested.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5057/2451 and links therein.

Comment: look at page 159 here  https://math.berkeley.edu/~kwray/papers/string_theory.pdf

Comment: @anna v What does string mode mean? Is it a certain state of vibration?

Comment: "closed string mode  expansion"  means "the way/manner of expanding a string"