# How does a magnet work?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

I'm having trouble understanding how a [magnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet) (not the [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) that is generated as a result but the material itself) work. The particles are aligned in a specific direction to give rise to force but I don't see how this alignment gives rise to "attraction" or force.

Comment: There are two wiki links for you. Please read it and focus your question a little bit. And, those particles are electrons. The property is determined by the alignment of the electron spins (unpaired or paired).

Comment: I like this answer to a duplicate question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/73668/4552

Answer (score 9):

Each electron has spin and it's own magnetic momentum, in sense each electron is just a very tiny magnet by it self, and there alignment makes there forces to be summed up, what makes a global one magnet, when electron mag. moments are chaotically aligned, the average sum is zero and your object will not behave as one big magnet.