# BICEP2 and string theory

Tags: string-theory, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background, string-theory-landscape

Can anybody elaborate on the implications of the BICEP2 result for string theory?

The discussion here [What experiment would disprove string theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-experiment-would-disprove-string-theory) suggests that refuting string theory is rather difficult. It did not mention that planned/ongoing experiments in the near future could exclude many string models by measuring the polarization of the CMB.

I now read that the BICEP2 result might rule out lots of string theory models. Is that true? If so, why? Is this result in the so-called "swampland"? How big a blow is this for string theory?

Comment: anecdata:  The string theorists I know are delighted about this result.

Comment: My anecdata: alternatives to string theory theorists are happy. Is each side claiming a victory?!

Comment: I think this post is the best place to start: http://motls.blogspot.com/2014/03/bicep2-primordial-gravitational-waves.html The result helps to rule out a large number of models.  The gravity waves weren't predictions of string theory, however, it was a prediction of applying quantum field theory to gravity.  We should find that confusing.  It came from a quantum gravity theory, but an incomplete application of it.  It looks like, however, string theory would directly predict the r value itself.  So maybe that's where we need those theories.

Comment: **Note to posterity**: the claimed discovery of primordial gravitational waves that this question references is now agreed to have been in error. See for example "[Gravitational waves discovery now officially dead](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature.2015.16830)".