# Is there any experimental setup to test if we are Boltzmann brains?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, universe

I am not sure if this subject belongs to mainstream physics. my question is motivated by the fact that I am not sure we could ever test if we are [Boltzmann brains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain). The same happens with string theory, Is there any reason to prefer one over the other (Occam's' razor should lean towards Boltzmann brains rather than string theory. I am correct?

Comment: More on [Boltzmann brains](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+Boltzmann+brain*).

Comment: ...what have Boltzmann brains to do with string theory? For a discussion of the testability of string theory, see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15/50583).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about any possible experiment, same for string theory, so I agree that both should not be considered mainstream physics but metaphysics. That is my own opinion, of course.

However, even if assuming a Boltzmann brain is simpler than string theory, it still needs to be complex enough to understand string theory, so I am not sure your argument holds. I would say that occam's razor favors string theory.

Comment: Boltzmann brains do not have a body, so I will take some of the comments as a joke. The complexity of a Boltzmann brain doesn't necessarily include understanding string theory: the reason being that I do not understand string theory myself, and have no idea if the people claiming to understand it do exist or are just a product of my imagination. So Boltzmann brains must be a simpler explanation than string theory