# Specific coupling constants, fermions and string theory

Tags: mass, string-theory, standard-model, elementary-particles, string-theory-landscape

Can string theory answer why the Yukawa couplings or the v.e.v.s.have the values they have in our Universe? I mean, why can string theory answer( and EXPLAIN) the question of why the top coupling to the Higgs is so big in comparison with the remaining particles? And with respect to fermions, can the Higgs coupling explain the tiny neutrino masses withour invoking Majorana conditions on the fermion fields? That is, can the Higgs sector select to be fine-tune the neutrinos to Majoranas with low couplings (excepting possible right-handed heavy neutrinos or sterile neutrinos) and heavy quarks to high couplings by some reason?

Comment: If a stringer presumes to tell you how the Yukawa couplings follow from string theory, somehow, anyhow, just don't believe her/him.

Comment: I know Cosmas, I KNOW, hehehehe...That is why ask...The landscape is terrible...

Comment: Yukawa couplings, indeed, follow from NO symmetry in the Standard Model. And as far as I know, excepting some rough trials in SUGRA or SUSY, there is no known origin based on currently accepted symmetry principles behind the Yukawa couplings. There is a big mystery and puzzle there!

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos, I don't know what message you want to convey. String theory has mechanisms to produce yukawa couplings, and for some vacua they can be crudely calculated. Are you just saying that no particular class of models has emerged as the clear leader?

Comment: Indeed, string theory has overindulged in speculation about the origin of the SM. I have not appreciated any compelling, defensible, broadly acceptable answer. Surely the OP has not asked for a gallimaufry of inconclusive models.

Comment: @Mitchell Porter String theory has no known way to select one vacua from another, so, we can not find a reason of why the Yukawa couplings in our Universe are these we observe, at least, to my knowledge (limited!). Of course, maybe some future genius could guess a way of picking the right vacua from the plenty of worlds that the string landscape (or the F-theory landscape) provides. However, I can not see a good reason in current formulations of string theory. Duality has changed the rules...And we can be wrong about what string theory is...Even low energy SUSY has a hard future...

Comment: And don't be wrong. I think something in SUSY is right, because we...do observe fermions! But, I have longly waited a way to punch the ugly MSSM and I think we will have to accept (fortunately!) that minimal SUSY and standard SUSY is WRONG. I highlight this, because some like SUSY has to exist in order to explain fermions. The way and the model Nature has chosen, well, is hidden at plain sight yet.