# Will string theory ever be provable?

Tags: string-theory

Some time ago I saw a documentary in which they said that to have the experimental certainty of the existence of a string we would need a particle accelerator with the same diameter of the milky way. Now such a thing seems to me (as a layman) asymptotically out of the possibilities of advanced civilizations to accomplish. 
Is this the only way to test beyond doubt the veracity of this theory or there are other sub-evidences that could either prove or disprove string theory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What experiment would disprove string theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15/)

Comment: If it could explain the unexplained fundamental constants of particle physics, that would be convincing. In principle, string theory can predict the values of such quantities, but in practice calculation is very difficult.